# Why Android 4.2 will try to fetch resource from drawable-xhdpi-v4

Tags: android

Recently, I get quite a number of crash reports

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/flag_au.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200bc
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1970)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
```

I feel strange that, as the crash reports are from **Android 4.2**, device **@Tab7QC-16**

I do have resource in **xhdpi**. I expect Android 4.2 should pick resources from **xhdpi**.

I don't plan to provide **drawable** folder. As, I will place mdpi sized image into it. When the targeted device scales up it to xhdpi, it will not look nice.

I think I can "solve" the crash, by cloning folder xhdpi to xhdpi-v4.

But, the question is, why Android 4 will try to fetch resource from drawable-xhdpi-v4?

Comment: Do you have shrinkResources enabled in your build.gradle script?

Comment: I don't see `shrinkResources = true` in my build.gradle. I assume it is false by default.

Comment: I suspect your crash is related to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79325. Have you updated to the Gradle tools plugin 1.4 or higher yet?

Comment: Ignore the -v4 btw -- it's a red herring. That's just how the resources get compiled into the APK.

Comment: Interesting bug! I'm using Gradle 1.1.0. But, isn't it strange, it only happen on selected device?

Comment: It's unfortunate, but it seems like some devices (seems to be Samsung devices) have an OS modification that causes problems with some of the compiler optimizations.

Comment: Have you tried extracting your APK? I did by change the extension to zip. The extracted APK contains the "drawable-xhdpi-v4" folder and the png which was not found by the device. Did you find any fixes?

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, folder resources work the exact opposite way.

The qualifier `drawable-v4`, for instance, refers to API level 4 and **higher**, not **lower**. So if you have these folders:

- drawable
- drawable-v4
- drawable-v15

The `drawable-v15` folder will stand for API 15-23 (up to now), `drawable-v4` for API 4-14, and `drawable` for API levels that do not get a match with previous folders (thus API 1-3).

You should probably reformat your folders in this sense.

[This is](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) the reference page in the official documentation. For some reason at this moment I can only load it in chinese (I think) but looking at the google cache it seems to support my opinion.